# Caja version used with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

Does Google Apps Script use the latest release of Caja for HtmlService or does it lag behind somewhat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is difference between latest Caja version and the Caja version of GAS.

- Caja version in the [Caja Playground](http://caja.appspot.com/) is `5065`
- GAS Caja version is `4969m`

The version information is stored in the `cajolerVersion` "variable" of HTML code produced by Caja.

Comment: Thank you megabyte. That is quiet informative. I didn't know this.

Comment: Is there any easy way to extract that value into a Google Apps Script variable?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access the version inside Apps Script although that's an interesting feature request. As a general rule, Apps Script lags Caja by about 2 weeks, give or take.